# using keys and constraints in sql server express

Tags: sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, reference, primary-key, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables :

```
**FamilyHeads**
HeadID   | HeadName      


**FamilyMembers**
MemberID  |  MemberName
```

Now, i want that if a family head exists , then only family members could be inserted in the FamilyMembers table. For this, should i include the HeadID column also in my FamilyMembers table and reference it from the FamilyHeads table. or what's the solution for this. I know that i have to use Primary and Foreign keys but not sure with the implementation. Please help with the code.

Comment: You don't have primary keys currently?

Comment: yes, currently i haven't assigned any keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add primary keys

```
ALTER TABLE FamilyHeads WITH CHECK ADD
     CONSTRAINT PK_FamilyHeads PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (HeadID)
GO
ALTER TABLE FamilyMembers WITH CHECK ADD
     CONSTRAINT PK_FamilyMembers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MemberID)
GO
```

Add columns for foreign key

```
--Same datatype, NOT NULL!
ALTER TABLE FamilyMembers ADD
    HeadID int NOT NULL
GO
```

Add FK

```
ALTER TABLE FamilyMembers WITH CHECK ADD
     CONSTRAINT FK_FamilyMembers_FamilyHeads FOREIGN KEY (HeadID)
            REFERENCES FamilyHeads (HeadID)
GO
```

Can you have duplicate HeadNames? if no

```
ALTER TABLE FamilyHeads WITH CHECK ADD
     CONSTRAINT UQ_FamilyHeads_HeadName UNIQUE (HeadName)
GO
```

If yes, how will you know which members to add to which head?

And add an non-unique index to FamilyMembers on HeadID

Comment: sir, what's the function of WITH CHECK & CLUSTERED while addition of primary key ? i know about CLUSTERED index but what's a clustered primary key?

Comment: search ALTER TABLE on the internet.

Comment: yes sir, i can have duplicate HeadNames as well as MemberNames, only the GroupCode would be different for each HeadName

Comment: sir, i read about ALTER TABLE, and found that, WITH CHECK is used when some data pre-exists in the tables & the keys are added afterwards? am i right sir?

Comment: @gbn: sir, i want that the group code is unique, so for this shall i add a unique constraint on the group code or make it a primary key?

Comment: when i create primary key, is a clustered index automatically created for that column on which the primary key is created?

Comment: @gbn: sir, what's the syntax to create a non-unique index to FamilyMembers on HeadID. also, by default the column HeadID is non-unique or unique, as it is referenced with the same column of FamilyHeads table? or do i have to create a non-unique on this column separately?